I am in the process to deploy my simple MERN website onto azure virtual machine. I have used nginx , pm2 for that. I am stuck onto some error now
the propblem is nginx is runnning fine i am able to see my react website, but the problem is i am not ableto fetch the details from my backend to frontend.
You can see the problem in the image i am facing.
i have setup the config file correctly. [enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/BLJZQ8zu.png)
enter image description here
I wanted to simply host onto a server using Nginx and pm2 to learn
have watched this guy video.
I am also confused to be able to host onto virtual machine , do i need to do anything logically to the code.
my code runs fine in vstudio.
but i have'nt done any changes to my code for deploying it.

Not able to see full stacktrace but localhost:3333 on a remote machine is not a valid address.

The backend's URL is set to localhost:3333 in the React app. It should be the URL of wherever it's deployed in Azure.

Change the port number, and try with your instance public IP address,
assume http://3.80.228.77/ is your instance public IP and this is your port 7053 use http://3.80.228.77:7053 in your frontend to hit APIs.

I have done this in my react file.
also in my server file of nginx i have edit the proxy to my VM address and then my port number like 0.000.00:3333 something like this.
but still the problem remain.
